# python regex pattern matching

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need to extract usernames and ids from a very big file.I am using python 2.7. I need to print anything that comes after username= or prId= and is with quotes " ".

**Input :**

```
1. username="null null”
2. username="test"
3. username="test name"
4. username="<unknown>"
5. prId="tokenKeyUser"
```

**The below should be matched:**

```
null null
test
test name
<unknown>
tokenKeyUser
```

Currently I am doing the below:

```
re.search(r'username="(.*?)"', line)
re.search(r'prId="(.*?)"', line)
```

This is able to find all patterns except **line 1** and **line 5**.

It is not able to find:
    1. "null null”
    2. "tokenKeyUser"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Line 1 seems to have a smart-quote terminating the quoted substring.

Comment: in first line I see two different chars `"` and `”`

Comment: ...and the second one matches for me.  Unable to reproduce the match failure.

Comment: Thanks DavidO. This works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boolean to make one regex expression to match all characters.

```
username="(.*?)["”]|prId="(.*?)"
```

group 1 will match username, and group 2 will match prId

Comment: The `|` character inside of a `[character class]` is incorrect. That is telling the regex engine to match a `"` character, or a `|` character, or a `”` character.  The `|` character is treated as a literal character within character classes, not as an alternation metacharacter. Character classes are implicitly one-character-wide alternations.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in file:
  for m in re.finditer(r'((?<=username=)|(?<=prId=))"([^"]+)["”]', line):
    print(m.group(0))

null null”
"test"
"test name"
"<unknown>"
"tokenKeyUser"
```

I thought I'd provide an approach for the exact output requirement.